# Broken USB ports. Can Ethernet ports be used instead?

Tags: usb, ethernet

Both the USB ports of my laptop have been damaged and are not working. Is there some way to connect USB devices to the Ethernet port by using some sort of USB-ethernet adapter?

Comment: TBH, depending on how the USB ports are damaged, it might be cheaper to get them replaced/repaired than to get a piece of bespoke, odd hardware

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

There are software solutions like [Flexihub](http://www.flexihub.com/usb-over-ip-software.html) where you can use USB devices of another PC. It works by installing the same software on both machines. It will probably consist of drivers that emulate the virtual device, a configuration UI to configure the source IP address and a driver on the source PC which captures the USB data and submits it to the target

There are also [hardware solutions](https://www.digi.com/products/usb-and-serial-connectivity/usb-over-ip-hubs/anywhereusb) which don't require an additional PC. They basically work the same way as the software, except that the device has the drivers already installed.

If you have detailed requirements like number of ports, speed and price, you may ask for a specific product on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I have personally use the [Lantronics UBox](http://lantronix.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/UBox_QS.pdf) but I was not happy with it, so I can only state that such hardware exists but I can't recommend a specific one.

Comment: while technically this answer provides alternatives, I believe the poster is looking for a cheap adapter.

Comment: @Keltari: I can only answer what was asked. I don't want to guess what OP wants.

Comment: And I don't understand the downvote, but who cares...

Comment: Well, a good answer wouldn't just throw out "you can do 'this this or this" You might actually want to talk about how to use these tools to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

No and yes.

No, as in not natively. There is no simple plug which just connects the Ethernets port wires to and USB plug and just works.

Yes, as in, the solution mentioned on Thomas' answer. Basically you use a normal USB setup in another computer/another device and make it appear as if it is local.

Note that this does require installed drivers, which usually means an active OS. As in, you cannot use a remotely attached USB keyboard to make changes in the BIOS or UEFI. You cannot boot from a remotely attached pendrive, etc etc.

And if you just want to access the data on USB pendrives than you might as well just put them in another computer and access the pendrive as a fileshare.

That having said: Which model lapop do you have? Express cards with 2x USB start around €13,90. And you could do the same with PCCARD, PCMCIA, Thunderbolt, Internal mini-PCI, internal mini-PCI-e, ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is USB sharing over WiFi. Did you look into product offerings from I/O gear?
https://www.iogear.com/product/GUWIP204/

This one works over CAT cable:

http://www.serialgear.com/USB-PRODUCT-DETAILS.cfm?sku=USBNET-400&catid=101&cats=101